# How to create "infected" .docx file

Tags: virus

I have a file scanner that checks if a file is infected or not, I want to make some tests, so I want to create some infected `.docx` or `.pdf` or `.xls` files and to see the response of the scanner to those files, my question: how can I create my own infected files without damaging my computer?

I know [EICAR](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) but this infected string works only on `.txt` files

Comment: are you *sure* it only works on txt files?

Comment: would renaming the txt file into a .docx file work for your tests?

Comment: Infected with... what?

Comment: @schroeder If I create a `.docx` file and copy paste EICAR string it tells me that the file is clean, some demo [here](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/ee7fd6f96a7ffed99b58c8f1fe77ead2bbd68d69b4b4a2ff89e0a2fceb48ccb3/detection)

Comment: what happens if you put it in the metadata or if you rename a txt to a docx?

Comment: @schroeder The thing is that my scanner doesn't support `.txt` so if I change `.txt` to `.docx` my scanner knows that it is not a a real `.docx` so he returns a "bad request"

Comment: I think that comment requires some explanation. Is this a scanner that you wrote?

Comment: ah, then they inspect the header to confirm file type, got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EICAR should work on any file name or extension. It is intended to be placed into a .COM file in the first place.

For Microsoft Office files, your best bet is to add a bunch of VBA macros in that try to create files with .exe extensions and write junk (perhaps EICAR) into them. For newer (e.g. xlsx, docx) files the format is just a ZIP, so you can also include EICAR into there as an embedded file too.

For PDF files you could use one of the known exploits for PDF readers, but make the payload benign. There's a [decent-ish tutorial here](https://www.drchaos.com/distributing-malware-inside-adobe-pdf-documents/) on how to generate PDF exploit payloads with Metasploit.